# How to add extra length to integer array in Python

Tags: python

I have a measurement device which is being read by Python into an integer array. How do I append the array with an extra 10 integer "locations"? I have tried ".extend", ".append", "+", and have not been able to make any of them work.

Summary Code:

```
    DataByte = []
    DataByte = Read_Instrument() # This fills DataByte
```

When I use:

```
    DataByte.append(1)
```

I get 'Array[int]' object has no attribute 'append'

If I try:

```
    DataByte.extend([1])
```

I get 'Array[int]' object has no attribute 'extend'

If I try:

```
    DataByte = DataByte + (1)
```

I get error message saying I can't combine integer with string

Comment: An integer array? You mean a list, like `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: In python there's no such a thing as a built-in array type. Perhaps you may be referring to [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=array#module-array)?

Comment: You must clarify the problem with a short contextualization.

Comment: Python typed arrays, the "array.array" objects support ".extend". What kind of array are you talking about?  Numpy ndarray?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append 10 elements to your list :

```
>>> [1,2,3]+[None]*10
[1, 2, 3, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```